# Excel: Keeping references/links when transposing

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet in where I have table (let's call it the summary table) with references  to a another table (among others) which is 2x40 (rows x columns). I would like to tranpose this into a 40x2 table. So, first I copy tha 2x40 and transpose it using Copy and then Paste Special -> Transpose (or using the TRANSPOSE() commando).

Then I would like to delete the 2x40 in order to avoid a dobulet of the information.

If I do this, the summary table will lose its references, since whatever value was in the now deleted table - the 2x40 is gone. However, the information is still availiable, but is now in the 40x2 table.

The easy solution would have been to CUT and then Paste SPecial -> Transpose, since the links are "dynamic" whenever I cut something. But Excel cannot do that for transposing for some reason.

So.. i'm out of ideas, except changing the summary table.

Is there anyway to go about this without having to change the references in the summary table?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible without keeping the original format around or modifying your summary table manually.

The reason the transpose isn't supported on pasting from a cut, is very likely the same reason you want to use it: it would be very difficult/impossible to update the references automatically for a transpose.

Any references that weren't to individual cells would have to also be transposed, which would require modifying the formulas, not just the references. Even for just relative references formulas that were once able to be drag filled would now break, (dragging down a column should move a reference left a column, but that's not what happens). So the only situation it would be easy to update would be if every reference to the transposed table were an absolute reference, at which point it would hardly be worth supporting.

If the summary table formulas are very complicated, I would recommend keeping both formats dynamically updated with the transpose array function. If not, then just update them to work with the new format.

Comment: I agree that "it would be very difficult (...) to update the references automatically for a transpose", but not that it would be "impossible". 7 years later and still no solution on this one?